# Azure Windows WebApp error - ESLint must be installed in order to run during builds: npm install --save-dev eslint

Tags: azure, deployment, next.js, azure-web-app-service, eslint

I'm currently trying to deploy a windows web app in Azure. I am using Nodejs, and specifically it's a next.js react app w/ typescript. I am running into errors in the deployment to azure.

I'm using github actions pipeline to build and deploy the application and when run there, `npm install` and `npm build` work without issue. The problem is when I have the `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` app setting set to `true` then I receive a lint error on the Deploy to Azure step since it is rebuilding the application on the web app. The error is:

```
error - ESLint must be installed in order to run during builds: npm install --save-dev eslint
```

I have `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` set to `true` because I had read earlier that node has issues with Azure webapps linking node packages, so you need to run the build on the server.

The issue is that when I run the build during the deployment, I read that the command `npm install --production` gets run. When this runs, it installs my packages properly, but then when it does the `postinstall` build step, it fails with the above eslint error.

When I have `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` set to `false` then the deployment succeeds in my pipeline, but the application doesn't work.

In the windows app I am not able to see the error logs, but previously when I had been deploying this as a Linux app, it showed missing packages due to the node_modules linking issue, so I am thinking it's the same issue on windows. (To view application logs I went to `Diagnose and Solve Problems -> Application Logs` and on windows I don't get the same options, everything I click just shows me graphs so I'm not sure how to verify it's the same issue but it seems to be.

**TLDR**

How do I fix the eslint error and successfully deploy my next.js application? Here is my package.json:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "postinstall": "next build"
  },
```

Am I just going about deploying a next.js application the wrong way on azure web app? Any guidance is appreciated. I've spent a few days trying to get this working at this point. Should I be creating a custom deploy script? I wasn't able to find documentation for doing that with node, but I see in the error output that the webapp runs

`azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted" -o "C:\home\site\deployments\tools" --node --sitePath "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted"'.` so is there a way to alter that?

Comment: try installing the eslint explicitly in the yaml while deployment or you can ignore the eslint in nextjs

Comment: when you say explicitly in the YAML, what are you referring to? I'm installing on a windows web app, so I have a custom build script, server.js, web.config, and the package.json file

Comment: try ignoring the eslint in next js refer this https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-eslint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is a work around to this error and that will be to ignore the `eslint` completely.
- This can be achieved by configuring the `next.config.js` by adding the  `ignoreDuringBuilds` option under the  `eslint`tag.
  The `next.config.js`  should look like this:

```
/** @type  {import('next').NextConfig} */
const  nextConfig = {
                        reactStrictMode:  true,
                        swcMinify:  true,
                    
                        eslint:{
                                    ignoreDuringBuilds :  true,
                                },
                    
                    }
module.exports = nextConfig
```

Here I have deployed Boilerplate nextjs code with the above next.config.js file.

[image]